# How do I find the file name associated with a socket descriptor?

Tags: linux, sockets, filenames

When I want to see the list of open files for a process using `ls -l /proc/pid/fd`, I see some socket descriptors. How can I find the respective file names?

```
lr-x------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 10 -> socket:[507942]
l-wx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 2 -> pipe:[505993]
l-wx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 22 -> pipe:[505994]
l-wx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 3 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 4 -> socket:[507938]
lrwx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 5 -> socket:[507939]
lrwx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 6 -> socket:[486323]
lrwx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 7 -> socket:[486324]
lrwx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 8 -> socket:[509999]
lrwx------ 1 u1 users 64 Sep 15 14:45 9 -> socket:[507941]
```

With `lsof -p pid` I also see sockets.

```
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  0r   CHR                1,3      0t0     1029 /dev/null
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  1u   CHR              136,3      0t0        6 /dev/pts/3
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  2w  FIFO                0,8      0t0   506122 pipe
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  3w   CHR                1,3      0t0     1029 /dev/null
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  4u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0   511127 socket
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  5u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0   511128 socket
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  6u  IPv4             510153      0t0      TCP *:37340 (LISTEN)
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  7u  IPv6             510154      0t0      TCP *:43305 (LISTEN)
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  8u  IPv4             512654      0t0      TCP hpclab.ws05:57696->hpclab.ws05:33141 (ESTABLISHED)
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  9u  IPv4             508030      0t0      TCP *:1027 (LISTEN)
atIcoFoam 24376 u1  10u  IPv6             508031      0t0      TCP *:1027 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: sockets don't always have respective file system names...

Comment: So how can I find the file names. Isn't there any way?

Comment: If a socket doesn't have a file name, then there's no way to find it.

Comment: But there is a file that this process is working on it

Answer (score 1):

Only named UNIX Domain Name sockets (`AF_UNIX` typed sockets) have a file associated.

**Update:**

The name of such a file is linked into the `/proc/<process id>/fd/` directory using the process specific value of the file descriptor for this socket.

All other sockets do not have a representation in the file system.

Comment: It just means, you will not find an entry in the file system for each an every socket `/proc/<pid>/fd` lists. @mahmood

Comment: SO how can I track the file name?

Comment: For none `AF_UNIX` sockets you simply can't as there is *no* file. For `AF_UNIX` sockets the corresponing entry in `/proc/<pid>/fd` will be a link to it. @mahmood

Comment: That is very odd. because there is an IO operation which can not be tracked!

Comment: For monitoring traffic via sockets `tcpdump` or `wireshark` might help. @mahmood

Comment: @mahmood, why do you say there is an IO operation which can not be tracked?

Comment: @Celada: Becasue I can not find which file is read or written!

Answer (score 0):

You can list open files by this:

```
lsof -p PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these UNIX listening sockets? I assume yes, because if they are anything else then your question doesn't make sense.

`lsof` is normally able to resolve the filesystem name that the socket is bound to:

```
lsof -p pid
```

Comment: Are you sure those sockets are bound to names? File descriptors 4 and 5 in your example might very well be the two ends of an anonymous UNIX socket created with `socketpair()`...